# Search and replace with multiple occurences of same pattern

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I want to replace the following

```
word-3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
second-example-3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
and-third-example-3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
```

I'm looking to replace the hyphen that occurs before the first 3 with a colon e.g.

```
word:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
second-example:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
and-third-example:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
```

So far, the closest I can get is

```
newvar=$(echo "$var" | sed 's/-[0-9]/:/')
```

but this solution replaces -3 with:

```
word:.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
second-example:.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
and-third-example:.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use captured group to retain the digit:

```
newvar=$(sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/:\1/' <<< "$var")
```

Result:

```
echo "$newvar"
word:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
second-example:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
and-third-example:3.4.4-r0-20170804_101145
```

Comment: I've checked the 3 solutions and they all work. I like the explanation given in Wiktor's solutions. It's something I can learn from. I'm accepting Roman's answer over John's as it's closest to what I originally had although there's really nothing to choose between them. I suspected I was close! Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9-]*\(-[^0-9-]*\)*\)-\([0-9]\)/\1:\3/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/cUyx8z)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\([^0-9-]*\(-[^0-9-]*\)*\)` - Group 1:

  - `[^0-9-]*` - any 0+ chars other than digits and `-`
  - `\(-[^0-9-]*\)*` - (Group 2) 0+ sequences of `-` and any 0+ chars other than digits and `-`
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `\([0-9]\)` - Group 3

The `\1` is the backreference to Group 1 contents and `\3` is the backreference to Group 3 contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
    newvar=$(echo "$var" | sed -r 's/-([0-9])/:\1/')
```

Very similar to other answers, but I prefer to use the -r option to sed, this allows constructing a sed String that is easier to read as it has fewer \ to parse. Like the other answers, the digit is capture by ([0-9]) and then replaced by \1.